# Angular read a file as string for dxf parser

Tags: angular

i would like to read a file as string.There is a file reader but it generate a text file. How do I convert it to String or is there a way to read file to String? Here is my code to read file to text.

```
upDxf(event : any){
   let file:File = event.target.files[0];
   let fileReader = new FileReader();

   fileReader.onload = (e) => {
     console.log(fileReader.result);
   }
   var text = fileReader.readAsText(file);
   console.log(text);
}
```

I need string to use it on dxf-parser from https://www.npmjs.com/package/dxf-parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.readAsText` reads file data as a text string already.
But the problem here is that `FileReader` is asynchronous, so at the time you log it, it's undefined.

You need to assign value to `text` in the `onload` method, and then from there pass it to the parser.

For example:

```
let text;

fileReader.onload = (e) => {

    console.log(fileReader.result);

    // now assign text
    text = fileReader.result as string;

    // send it to parser
    // this.parse(text);
}

// text is undefined here..
fileReader.readAsText(file);
```

or, you can use [`.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) with async/await and get the result synchronously:

```
async upDxf(event: any) {

    let file: File = event.target.files[0];

    // block until it's done
    const text = await file.text();
    
    // result
    console.log('text: ', text);
    //this.parse(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The second one does it. The first one gives "Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to parameter type of 'string'.

Comment: right, types were missing for `text` variable. try now

Comment: Wow now both are the answers. Thank you.